# How to to send and retrieve data from flickr flickr.test.echo method using JQuery Ajax REST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, flickr

I want to display whatever the response of flickr.test.echo was on the page using rest (jquery ajax - because thats what im using)

I need to supply an api_key

---

The REST Endpoint URL is http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/

To request the flickr.test.echo service, invoke like this:

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&name=value

By default, REST requests will send a REST response.

To return the response in REST format, send a parameter "format" in the request with a value of "rest". When using the REST request method, the response defaults to REST.

A method call returns this:

[xml-payload-here]

If an error occurs, the following is returned:

I got that from here http://www.flickr.com/services/api/request.rest.html

---

This is the method I'm interested in http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.test.echo.html

please help.

Comment: What is your problem, exactly? You can't supply the API key to the $.ajax call?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you're going to retrieve their data with Ajax, since Ajax doesn't work cross-domain.

Have you seen their $.getJSON demo?
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

It lets you specify a callback and returns json wrapped as a parameter inside an automatically generated function. It works cross-domain as well.

Comment: little too old BUT jsop and json it's the same the only thing is that jsonp returnt the value of the json inside of a function which let the crossbrowser policy to work. But in both cases are AJAX call, actually JSONP work pretty in the same way than an AJAX call, (irony but while ajax was named because xml - with jsonp you use the same approach) So basically his question is right.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Flickr's JSON format](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) API and `jQuery.getJSON` like sktrdie suggested - just remember to append `callback=?` to the url to wrap it in [JSONP](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding).

From the [jQuery.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) docs:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gnetags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&callback=?",
    function(data){
      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
        if ( i == 4 ) return false;
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the [jQuery-Flickr plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-flickr/), a lot easier! :)